# How to set offset for the first element of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, collectionview

I want to set offset offset for the first element of collectionView, so the first cell will apear in the center of the collectionView. [image: See photo]

Comment: And what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can try to set the `contentOffset` of your `UICollectionView`, to `(yourCollectionView.width-firstElement.widh)/2.` on the y.

Answer (score 12):

Put this in your ViewDidLoad:

```
yourCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: yourCollectionView.frame.width/2, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This sets the inset for every cell of the collection view though. How do we get it to do it for the first cell only? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it with UIEdgeInsets. It can be set either in interface builder or in code by setting sectionInsets property of UICollectionViewFlowLayout